# JS Consistent Timeouts Between Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, browser, timeout

I'm trying to make a timer that is consistent between browsers, but some users of my site have reported that the timer ticks down much faster in some browsers than others. Specifically, it seems like Chrome runs real-time, while Safari and Firefox have a much slower countdown. Here is the code that handles the timer:

```js
async function countDown(){
    if(!gameIsRunning)
        return;

    if(timeRemaining <= 0){
        gameOver();
        return;
    }

    // Immediately Set timeout for next countdown step
    setTimeout(() => {
        countDown();
        // console.log(timeRemaining)
    }, COUNTDOWN_STEP);

    // Apply countdown
    timeRemaining -= COUNTDOWN_STEP;
    updateTimeBar();
}
```

The function sets a timeout to call itself.
Is there a way to make this consistent? Would a loop that sleep(10ms) be more consistent?

Comment: Don't count yourself to track time. Instead of using `timeRemaining -= COUNTDOWN_STEP;`, get the actual current time.

Comment: No, a busy loop will make it worse.